# how to define the space where objects or boxes can be placed

Tags: c#

I am doing a project based on container loading problem.  I need to define the container as a space for loading boxes. The loaded boxes need to get the coordinates where it has been placed. Here, I need help on how to define the space.

```
namespace Get3Dcordinates
{
    class Spacecordinates
    {
        public struct Point3D
        {
            public int x {get;set;}
            public int y {get;set;}
            public int z {get;set;}
            public int value {get;set;}
            //any other properties....
        }
        List<Point3D>ListofPoints=new List<Point3D>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to me, you should model like this,

```
public struct Point3D
{
    public   int x {get;set;}
    public   int y {get;set;}
    public   int z {get;set;}
    public   int value {get;set;}
    //any other properties....
}

public class Box
{
    public int width {get; set;}
    public int length {get; set;}
    public int height {get; set;}
}

public class ContainerItem
{
    public Box box {get; set;}
    public Point3D boxPlacement {get; set;}
    public Container container {get; set;}
}

public class Container
{
    public int width {get; set;}
    public int length {get; set;}
    public int height {get; set;}

    public List<ContainerItem> boxes {get; set;}
}
```

Now, based on placement point of particular box and it's height-width-length attributes, you can define some methods to get which co-ords are vacant and which are occupied to decide place to load new box or reorganize boxes...

Hope, it'll help you.